# Dynamically inserted React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm building a WYSIWYG tool in React/flux where you build interfaces by dragging and dropping elements onto a page. So for instance, I have a list of droppable elements: List, Form, Input Box, Text Box, etc. When the user drops one of those elements on the page, I need to insert the associated react component (and I store a name property of the object they drop, so I will know the component name I need). So if a user drops a list onto the page, and my associated component tag is `<list />`, I can't do just   `<{component.name} />` and it will turn it into `<list />`...yet I need a method of doing so. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So fiddling around with this, I ended up getting it to work like this:

```
var Sort = require('./sort')
var List = require(./list')

var allComponents = {
    sort: Sort,
    list: List
}

React.createElement(allComponents[component.componentName], {data:component.data})
```

so now if my component.componentName is list, it will render the  component, and data will become my properties